# Regex to match string containing exactly two equal words in any order

Tags: regex

I need logical AND in regex for exactly two equal names.

something like

house AND house in any order

match with following strings

- 'one house two house'
- 'house car boat house apple'
- 'house house car'

no match with following strings (e.g.)

- 'one house two house three house'  (there are 3 house words , there should be 2 house words)
- 'an house car'     (there is only 1 house , there should be 2 house words)
- 'car boat tree home'  (there is no house word , there should be 2 house words)

Comment: BTW my question was very different ! That post does not solve my question in no way.

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/k2aCok/1